# Add Time to Date Action Item - Add Business Days

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, nintex

I'd like use an "Add Time to Date" action item for my reminder notifications. I'd like to add 1 business day.

Does anyone know how to specify "days" as "business days"?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge that cannot be done via oob approaches. I assume you are configuring a sharepoint workflow using this action, you cannot customize the action here. Mostly we will use calculated column as workarounds.

https://www.sharepointeurope.com/two-easy-ways-to-calculate-working-days-inside-a-sharepoint-workflow/

http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/working-days-weekdays-holidays-sharepoint-calculated-columns/